# Add torrent with web api

Tags: python, python-requests, utorrent

I'm trying to add a torrent with uTorrent web api (http://www.utorrent.com/community/developers/webapi), in Python using Requests library.

```
import requests
import re

UTORRENT_URL = 'http://%s:%s/gui/' % ('localhost', '55655')
UTORRENT_URL_TOKEN = '%stoken.html' % UTORRENT_URL
REGEX_UTORRENT_TOKEN = r'<div[^>]*id=[\"\']token[\"\'][^>]*>([^<]*)</div>'


auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('x', 'x')
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(UTORRENT_URL_TOKEN, auth=auth, headers=headers)
token = re.search(REGEX_UTORRENT_TOKEN, r.text).group(1)
guid = r.cookies['GUID']
cookies = dict(GUID = guid)

headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
params = {'action':'add-file','token': token}
files = {'torrent_file':'C:\\x.torrent'}
r = requests.post(UTORRENT_URL, auth=auth, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, params=params, files=files)
print r.json()
```

Error - torrent file content not supplied in form parameter

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was setting the **headers**. Removing them and it finally works!

```
import requests
import re

UTORRENT_URL = 'http://%s:%s/gui/' % ('192.168.1.80', '55655')
UTORRENT_URL_TOKEN = '%stoken.html' % UTORRENT_URL
REGEX_UTORRENT_TOKEN = r'<div[^>]*id=[\"\']token[\"\'][^>]*>([^<]*)</div>'

auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('x', 'x')
r = requests.get(UTORRENT_URL_TOKEN, auth=auth)
token = re.search(REGEX_UTORRENT_TOKEN, r.text).group(1)
guid = r.cookies['GUID']
cookies = dict(GUID = guid)

params = {'action':'add-file','token': token}
files = {'torrent_file': open('C:\\x.torrent', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url=UTORRENT_URL, auth=auth, cookies=cookies, params=params, files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending the file data. You should read the [relevant section of the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). The correct code would be this (I marked the line I changed):

```
import requests
import re

UTORRENT_URL = 'http://%s:%s/gui/' % ('localhost', '55655')
UTORRENT_URL_TOKEN = '%stoken.html' % UTORRENT_URL
REGEX_UTORRENT_TOKEN = r'<div[^>]*id=[\"\']token[\"\'][^>]*>([^<]*)</div>'


auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('x', 'x')
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(UTORRENT_URL_TOKEN, auth=auth, headers=headers)
token = re.search(REGEX_UTORRENT_TOKEN, r.text).group(1)
guid = r.cookies['GUID']
cookies = dict(GUID = guid)

headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
params = {'action':'add-file','token': token}
files = {'torrent_file': open('C:\\x.torrent', 'rb')}  # Changed this line
r = requests.post(UTORRENT_URL, auth=auth, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, params=params, files=files)
print r.json()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid the same error is printed (Error - torrent file content not supplied in form parameter)